# Unable to install `@nuxtjs/sentry` in Node 16.14 docker container. Permission errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I'm trying to install `@nuxtjs/sentry` using `npm install @nuxtjs/sentry`. These are the errors I'm getting.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/@sentry/cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./scripts/install.js
npm ERR! info sentry-cli Downloading from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/1.74.4/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-24T08_02_47_860Z-debug-0.log
exited with code 1
```

Comment: Hi, more context would be quite helpful here (your system, configuration etc). Also, did you tried using other node.js versions? Tried with yarn? Did you checked the Github related to the package?

Comment: @kissu I'm using docker. The docker image is node:16.14. I don't kinda want to downgrade because it's the live product. Idk if it's a good option to downgrade. I didn't try yarn yet, been using the npm throughout the project.

Comment: Try to get it out of docker and see if it works well. Downgrading may be a way of debugging the whole thing. You need to try some stuff if you want to make progress. Same goes for yarn.

Comment: Let me try it with node 14 and yarn as well.

Comment: @kissu It is working with yarn and also on node 14

Comment: Alright, continue to debug so. Try other 16.x version, try with yarn etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `unsafe-perm`

either:

add a file called `.npmrc` in your project's root directory and put this in it

```
unsafe-perm=true
```

OR

just use this command before installing (I didn't confirm this)

```
sudo npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Basically npm would download the packages as root but then try to install the binaries as a local user without root permissions so it wouldn't have access to the directory where the binaries were downloaded at.

You just better double check the packages that you install to make sure they are trustworthy, otherwise it's safe to do so

> Note: I only tried it on node 14, didn't test it on node 16

Comment: Hm, why such thing would be needed in the first place. Seems quite critical and unsafe by default (if you don't spend your evenings reading source code of the packages that you install).

Comment: @kissu it's not the package itself, it's the package binaries that gets shipped with it (if any) you can read more about it here https://geedew.com/What-does-unsafe-perm-in-npm-actually-do/